# How do I create a new factor level that summarizes total values of other factor levels?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset where I have at least three columns

```
  year sex value
1 2019   M    10
2 2019   F    20
3 2020   M    50
4 2020   F    20
```

I would like to group by the first column, year, and then add another level to sex that corresponds the total value in column 3, that is, I would like something like this:

```
   year sex   value
  <int> <chr> <dbl>
1  2019 M        10
2  2019 F        20
3  2019 Total    30
4  2020 M        50
5  2020 F        20
6  2020 Total    70
```

Any help is appreciated, especially in dplyr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is just another way of doing this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_split(year) %>%
  map_dfr(~ add_row(.x, year = first(.x$year), sex = "Total", value = sum(.x$value)))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
   year sex   value
  <int> <chr> <dbl>
1  2019 M        10
2  2019 F        20
3  2019 Total    30
4  2020 M        50
5  2020 F        20
6  2020 Total    70
```

Comment: It worked and it was fast - Thank you! FYI, I had another column (region) in addition to year but simply piping group_by(year, region) before using the group_split function and your code worked. Thanks again. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Yes it is recommended to use `group_by` first and then `group_split` sometimes. Just keep in mind that for variable like `year` I chose only one `first` or `last` no difference, and for variables like `value` where you need an average or sum you can apply a function on the whole variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can summarise the data for each year and bind it to the original dataset.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(sex = 'Total', 
            value = sum(value)) %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(year, sex)

#   year sex   value
#  <int> <chr> <dbl>
#1  2019 F        20
#2  2019 M        10
#3  2019 Total    30
#4  2020 F        20
#5  2020 M        50
#6  2020 Total    70
```

Or in base R -

```
aggregate(value~year, df, sum) |>
  transform(sex = 'Total') |>
  rbind(df)
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(year = rep(2019:2020, each = 2), 
                 sex = c('M', 'F'), value = c(10, 20, 50, 20))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help this also worked magically!